# Capture UIImage from UIView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage

Im trying to capture a `UIImage` from a `UIView` using imagecontext

```
func captureImage() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, true, 0.0)
    self.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return img
}
```

*I have also tried using `renderinContext()`*

I have this in an `extension` of `UIView`

I use this to get an Image from a `MapBoxView` which is a subclass `UIView`

```
if let viewImage = self.mapView?.resizableSnapshotViewFromRect(frame, afterScreenUpdates: false, withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsZero) {
    let img = viewImage.captureImage()

    self.view.addSubview(UIImageView(image: img))
}
```

The img that is getting returned from the `captureImage()` function is just black...

`viewImage` has its right contents when I add that to the view instead, so there is something wrong with the capture method.

Answer (score 0):

`resizableSnapshotViewFromRect` return UIView object, but you don't add this object to view hierarchy, and don't display this view. 
So in this case `self.drawViewHierarchyInRect` will draw nothing.

Why you don't capture UIImage directly from mapView?

```
if let img = self.mapView?.captureImage() {
    self.view.addSubview(UIImageView(image: img))
}
```

Comment: The reason I did like this is because I only want a part of the mapview, not the whole thing.

Comment: in this case use your code, but add your viewImage to view hierarchy, but below all views, but anyway, you get same result - image for whole map view...

Answer (score 0):

To get snapshot from MapView, you can also take a help of `MKMapSnapshotter` class.

See following:

```
func takeSnapShot {

    var options = MKMapSnapshotOptions()
    options.region = self.mapView.region
    options.scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

    var snapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)
    snapshotter .startWithCompletionHandler { (var snapShot: MKMapSnapshot!, var error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var image = snapShot.image as UIImage!
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I have explored **[MapBox RMMapView](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/blob/release/MapView/Map/RMMapView.h)** and found that there is a method to take a snap shot from map.

```
- (UIImage *)takeSnapshot;
```

Yes you can take a snap from specific part of map. The class `MKMapSnapshotOptions` has property `size`, You can pass size which you want in above code.

```
func takeSnapShot {

    var options = MKMapSnapshotOptions()
    options.region = self.mapView.region
    options.scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

    // The size of the image to create. Defaults to 256x256
    options.size = CGSizeMake(100, 100);

    var snapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)
    snapshotter .startWithCompletionHandler { (var snapShot: MKMapSnapshot!, var error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var image = snapShot.image as UIImage!
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not a MapKit mapview, its a Mapbox, I cant find mapView.region

Comment: @Arbitur- Actually there is ready made method available to take snapshot, have you tried that?

Comment: Yea I just found it x), but that captures the whole map and not just a part of it :(

Comment: Well I dont get how Ill get the image because Im not using MKMapView, Im using RMMapView. And the takeSnapShot() -> UIImage takes a snap of the whole map.

Comment: Look, If you check `MKMapView` it is subclass of `UIView` and same as `RMMapView`. In `RMMapView` they have used `projectedBounds` to get region of map. So the names are different but internally all works same.

Answer (score 0):

Define a macro for OS_VERSION as:

```
#define OS_VERSION [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]
```

To get the snapshot image of any view you can use this method:

```
- (UIImage *)takeSnapshotOfView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);

    if (OS_VERSION < 7.0)
    {
        [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    }
    else
    {
        [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    }

    UIImage *snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return snapshot;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Im only using ios 7+ so no need to check for os version

Comment: @Arbitur try this `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);` You are passing `true` as a second parameter. Try to make it `false`.